Is there a way to make a new tkinter window flash orange on the taskbar until clicked?
There's a window that will appear with a message after some condition is met, its not a message_box, its a regular window with a label. I want that window to flash orange on the taskbar until its clicked once, but i can't find a way to do it using tkinter.
end = Tk()
end.after(1000, lambda: win.focus_force())
end.title('FreteFinder')
end.attributes('-topmost', True)
end.geometry("450x250")
end.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')

Label(end).grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=W, padx=15, pady=5)
label = tkFont.Font(size=28)
label = Label(end, text="Novo Frete Encontrado!",font=("Arial", 20))
label.place(anchor=CENTER, relx=0.5, rely=0.5)
end.mainloop()


It is OS system related.  If your platform is Windows, try ctypes.windll.user32.FlashWindow().

It worked after a small modification, the final code looks like this ctypes.windll.user32.FlashWindowEx(ctypes.byref(flash_info)) . Thanks a lot!

Try this instead:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font as tkFont
import ctypes
import platform

def flash_window(window):
    if platform.system() == "Windows":
        ctypes.windll.user32.FlashWindow(ctypes.windll.user32.GetForegroundWindow(), True)
    window.after(1000, lambda: flash_window(window))

def stop_flashing(event):
    if platform.system() == "Windows":
        ctypes.windll.user32.FlashWindow(ctypes.windll.user32.GetForegroundWindow(), False)

end = tk.Tk()
end.title('FreteFinder')
end.attributes('-topmost', True)
end.geometry("450x250")
end.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')

flash_window(end)
end.bind("<Button-1>", stop_flashing)

label = tk.Label(end, text="Novo Frete Encontrado!", font=("Arial", 20))
label.place(anchor=tk.CENTER, relx=0.5, rely=0.5)

end.mainloop()


Did you test your solution? stop_flashing() does not stop the after loop of calling flash_window().

It didn't flash like I expected but @acw1668 made it work. Thanks for your help!
